# Determine if the function is injective or surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Hi how do i determine if this linear function is injective or surjective (at the variation of k in R)?

[image]

Comment: Type the question in English. Use mathjax. Include your attempts.

Comment: Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown 
But how do I determine if it is injective or surusative with gauss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix

$A:=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1\\
1 & 0 & 5 \\
2 & 3 & k
\end{bmatrix}$.

Then we have:

$f$ is surjective $ \iff f$ is injective $ \iff \det A \ne 0$.

Comment: Very clear thanks!!!